# Dynamically add custom layout to ArrayList based on data from excel file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, apache-poi, android-arrayadapter

Here i want to add row (custom layout) to an ArrayList dynamically based on data from excel. Everything working just fine except that i only get the last values of ArrayAdapter loaded.

First off here is the declaration of my instance variables:

```
List<Record> model = new ArrayList<Record>();
RecordAdapter adapter = null;
```

This is part of the code i believe is a problematic area.

```
class RecordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Record> {
    RecordAdapter() {
        super(Census.this, R.layout.row, model);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        RecordHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            holder = new RecordHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(model.get(position));
        return (row);
    }
}
```

This is the RecordHolder class:

```
static class RecordHolder {
    TextView tvEntryNo = null;
    TextView tvPNO = null;
    TextView tvDefoliator = null;
    TextView tvLpF = null;
    CheckBox cbOryctes = null;
    CheckBox cbTermite = null;
    CheckBox cbRat = null;
    private ImageView icon = null;

    RecordHolder(View row) {
        tvEntryNo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvEntry);
        tvPNO = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvPNO);
        tvDefoliator = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvDefoliator);
        tvLpF = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvLpF);
        cbOryctes = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cbOryctes);
        cbTermite = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cbTermite);
        cbRat = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.cbRat);
        icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    void populateFrom(Record r) {
        tvEntryNo.setText("Pokok ke: " + r.getEntryNo());
        tvPNO.setText("PNO: " + r.getPNO());
        tvDefoliator.setText("Species: " + r.getDefSpec());
        tvLpF.setText("Larva: " + r.getLpF());
        int temp = 0;

        int counter = 0;

        if (r.isOrycDmg()) {
            cbOryctes.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            cbOryctes.setChecked(false);
        }

        if (r.isTermiteDmg()) {
            cbTermite.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            cbTermite.setChecked(false);
        }

        if (r.isRatDmg()) {
            cbRat.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            cbRat.setChecked(false);
        }

        if ((r.getDefSpec() == "Setora Nitens" || r.getDefSpec() == "Setothosea Asigna" ||
                r.getDefSpec() == "Mahasena Corbetti") && Integer.parseInt(r.getLpF().toString()) > 5) {
            counter++;
        }

        if (!r.getLpF().trim().equals("")) {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(r.getLpF());
        }
        if (temp > 10) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (r.isOrycDmg()) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (r.isTermiteDmg()) {
            counter++;
        }
        if (r.isRatDmg()) {
            counter++;
        }

        if (r.getPnD_Time().trim().equals("")) {
            //New Data
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
        } else if (counter == 0) {
            //Negligible problem
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_alert);
        } else if (counter == 1) {
            //need attention, minor problem
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_alert);
        } else {
            //serious problem
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_alert);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the loadData() method that i use to load data from excel file:

```
public void loadData() {
    //Instantiate holder
    Record r = new Record();
    try {
        //get the excel file
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //parse data from excel to holder
        for (int i = FIRST_ROW_TO_GET; i <= (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            //New Data
            if (row == null) {
                r.setFormNo(filename(fileName));
                r.setEntryNo(String.valueOf(i));
                r.setPNO("Data Baru");
                r.setDefSpec("Tidak Ada");
                r.setLpF("");
                r.setOrycDmg(false);
                r.setTermiteDmg(false);
                r.setRatDmg(false);
                r.setSampler("");
                r.setPnD_Date("");
                r.setPnD_Time("");

            } else {
                //Existing Data
                for (int cn = row.getFirstCellNum(); cn <= row.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
                    Cell c = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                    //Blank cells handler
                    if (c == null) {
                        switch (cn) {
                            case 0:
                                r.setFormNo(filename(fileName));
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                r.setEntryNo(String.valueOf(i));
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                r.setPNO("Data Baru");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                r.setDefSpec("Tidak Ada");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                r.setLpF("");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                r.setOrycDmg(false);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                r.setTermiteDmg(false);
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                r.setRatDmg(false);
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                r.setSampler("");
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                r.setPnD_Date("");
                                break;
                            case 10:
                                r.setPnD_Time("");
                                break;
                        }

                    } else {
                        //non empty cells handler
                        switch (cn) {
                            case 0:
                                r.setFormNo(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                r.setEntryNo(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                r.setPNO(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                r.setDefSpec(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                r.setLpF(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                if (Integer.parseInt(c.getStringCellValue()) == 1)
                                    r.setOrycDmg(true);
                                else
                                    r.setOrycDmg(false);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                if (Integer.parseInt(c.getStringCellValue()) == 1)
                                    r.setTermiteDmg(true);
                                else
                                    r.setTermiteDmg(false);
                                break;
                            case 7:
                                if (Integer.parseInt(c.getStringCellValue()) == 1)
                                    r.setRatDmg(true);
                                else
                                    r.setRatDmg(false);
                                break;
                            case 8:
                                r.setSampler(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 9:
                                r.setPnD_Date(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 10:
                                r.setPnD_Time(c.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            adapter.add(r);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Record.java only contains declarations of variables. The apps compiled just fine but i encounter a problem that it only populate the ListView with the last values of LoadData() looping. I'm suspicious that the problem comes from my getView() method. Can someone help to point out where i might be making mistake?

I'll be happy to provide additional codes needed. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: what do you mean by _"populate the ListView with the last values of LoadData() looping"_? Can you explain this more clearly? where do you call `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: in the //parse data from excel to holder section in the loadData() function. I try to load everything from the excel file until the last row of that file + 1 row (for new data). Let's say i have 4 row of data in excel file. Logically the looping should populate the ListView with 4 row data and only on the 5th row it will be showing the row == null (for new data). But what i got is the ListView got populated with 5 rows of new data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init a new `Record` object within the loop. Otherwise it will update the same object and show the same data for each row.

```
public void loadData() {
    try {
        //get the excel file
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //parse data from excel to holder
        for (int i = FIRST_ROW_TO_GET; i <= (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1); i++) {
            Record r = new Record(); // move this HERE
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            ...
            ...
```